# localhost/examples is not finding?

Tags: tomcat, xampp, tomcat7, tomcat8, tomcat6

Till yesterday every servlet was running on localhost/examples/servlet-name as per the url pattern set by me.But now my tomcat shows this when i try to access any file 
with localhost/examples
localhost/examples/[anything that was previously running]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug0NB.png)

it also shows the same for localhost:8080/doc
Only its homepage withurl http://localhost is working.
How to Solve it?
I am using XAMPP for it.

Comment: Please have a look at the Tomcat logs.  The first thing I would suspect is that your web app didn't startup properly.  That would explain the 404 error.  So would other things, such as the context/servlet names changing, but check the logs first.

Comment: please explain these answer.

Comment: I already explained it, just check the logs folder of your Tomcat installation.  If you don't have access to it, then you need to get in touch with the owner of that web app.

Comment: Done.There was error in code of deployment descriptor.